# ToolBox, Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, sql, windows, visual-studio-2010, forms

I've created Windows Form Application for Visual Studio 2010 with C# so that I can make the form execute SQL statements from my Database. I've looked through several tutorials and examples and many of them include a toolbox for adding options to the form. I do not have this form about creating or resetting Visual Studio, and I have no Idea where it can be found. At this point my only options are coding each "thing" i want on the form one by one but for time constraints I can't really do this. Can anyone tell me how I can get or find this toolbox of controls?

Comment: You might want to consider more fundamental aspects of C# before you attempt interacting with a database.

Answer (score 1):

To open the toolbox, go to `View` -> `Toolbox`. Or you can use the `Ctrl-W, X` shortcut.

You must have a `Form` to place your controls on. Make sure you add a new `Form` to your project, then double click on it to view the blank form. Using the toolbox, you can drag and drop new controls onto your form.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ctrl+Alt+X` to bring up the Toolbox.

Or go to View menu and select "Toolbox".